# Ada tasks and termination

Tags: multithreading, task, ada

I've been reading a little bit about tasks in ada at http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Tasking and thought that i'll write a little thing with tasks myself. Since i've read a small course on Pintos recently i thought i'd implement a little readers-writers algorithm. This is my attempt at it:

```ada
procedure Test_Queue is

   type Int_Array is array(1..10) of Integer;

   task type Queue is
      entry Quit;
      entry Pop(Elem : out Integer);
      entry Push(Elem : in Integer);
   end Queue;

   task body Queue is
      Elems_In_Queue : Integer := 0;
      Q : Int_Array;
   begin
      loop
         select
            accept Push(Elem : in Integer) do
               Put_Line("Push");
               Elems_In_Queue := Elems_In_Queue + 1;
               Q(Elems_In_Queue) := Elem;
            end Push;
         or
            when Elems_In_Queue > 0 =>
               accept Pop(Elem : out Integer) do
                    Put_Line("Pop");
                Elem := Q(Elems_In_Queue);
                Elems_In_Queue := Elems_In_Queue - 1;
               end Pop;
         else
            delay 1.0;
            Put_Line("Waited");
            accept Quit;
            exit;
         end select;
      end loop;
      Put_Line("Got out of the loop");
   end Queue;

   Q : Queue;
   X : Integer;

begin
   Put_Line("Started");
   Q.Push(10);
   Put_Line("Pushed");
   Q.Push(11);
   Put_Line("Pushed");
   Q.Pop(X);
   Put_Line("Integer:" & Integer'Image(X));
   Q.Quit;
   Put_Line("Done");
end Test_Queue;
```

Might be worth mentioning that the behaviour i would like to see is that when no operations (push/pop) have been made to the queue/stack for 1 second i would like the task to terminate/exit the infinite loop.

But this just outputs "Started" and then goes to my delay 1.0 and outputs "Wait". This is not exactly what I expected since i have accept for at least push and that is the first thing i call. Where have i been thinking wrong and why doesn't this work? Also, are there any more sources with some examples as for how to do tasking in Ada? I managed to implement this by creating a Semaphore and Lock in 2 different tasks but that seemed to be a bad solution and not very adaesque.

Comment: Nice looking little example. The first thing I would do is improve diagnostics a little : let the Queue task report "Pushing", "Popping" or "Waiting", and report what you see in the question.

Comment: Followed your advice, thanks! It would seem that my select goes into the delay directly, is it because the delay is the first thing that's open when the task starts and then it gets stuck in there waiting to accept my call to quit?

Comment: Your hypothesis looks correct; there will be a different variant of the select statement that does exactly what you want. I ought to know the answer offhand, since I've been reading Burns and Welling in my spare moments!

Comment: After a quick scan of B&W, I think the Delay should be in another "OR" alternative rather than the "ELSE" alternative. (see B&W p.108 if you have it handy)

Comment: Thanks a heap! That got everything rolling as i exepected for now! Is http://www.amazon.com/Concurrent-Real-Time-Programming-Alan-Burns/dp/0521866979 the book you meant? Would you mind posting some kind of answer so that i have something to accept and give you some well deserved credit for? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having improved the diagnostics, it is clear that on startup, neither of the `Select` alternatives was immediately available so the Queue task was going straight to the `Else` part, and after 1 second delay, waiting to accept `Quit`.

Meanwhile the main task was blocking on its first (unconditional, untimed!) `Push` entry call, so that it could never issue the `Quit` entry call. Result : Deadlock.

The solution (described in [Burns & Welling](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521866979) on p.108) is simply to change `ELSE` to `OR` so that the third (Delay) option is still a `Select` alternative. Then in each iteration, the earliest of (Push, Pop or Delay) will be accepted.

Comment: Thanks again! Really glad for the help!

Comment: Right. It is important to realise that guards on select statement branches are only evaluated at the top of the select statement. If a guard becomes open while you are waiting, that will not be seen by the select statement until you come around the loop and exectute it again.